# Davening by a Tzaddik on Rosh HaShanah

Tags: minhag, tefilla, rosh-hashanah-new-year, chasidut-hasidism, tzaddikim

Where does the inyan of davening with a Tzaddik on Rosh HaShanah come from? Where did it start? Was there ever such a minhag before chassidus come along? (Assuming it started with the Chassidim -- my question before this was with *which* chassididm did it start with since that was my assumption.)

Comment: Live Tzadikkim?

Comment: Yes, let's start with Tzaddikim that are physically alive

Comment: Perhaps the Tzaddik lifting the overall (spiritual) level of the Tzibbur, so people try to be part of that Tzibbur.

Comment: The question was in the history, where did it start? By Chassidim? Before Chassidim? Not so much the reasons...

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83924/rabbi-nachman-on-connecting-to-tzaddikim-and-tefillah/84585#84585